# Concurrency with shell_exec() in PHP

Tags: php, shell-exec, fontforge

I have a web application which runs FontForge shell commands using `shell_exec()` in PHP. I'm worried about potential concurrency issues. Is there a way to make `shell_exec()` open a unique instance for each user?

One of the commands allows users to convert fonts from one file format to another:

```
$command = "fontforge -c 'Open($1); Generate($2)' ".$format1." ".$format2;
shell_exec($command);
```

I'm worried that if USER A opens FONT A and USER B immediately opens FONT B (before the Generate() command for USER A is called), then USER A would mistakenly receive FONT B, since FONT B is currently the 'open' font.

Comment: What kind of commands are you running? What do they do?

Comment: It will have different PID.. How otherwise is that an issue?

Comment: I updated the post with an example...

Comment: Just use different output files (e.g. with IP prefix) for every user.

Comment: This has to do with the source and output file, as well as how you manage your parameters.  Furthermore, I suspect you're opening yourself up to your users executing whatever they want on your server.  In any case, more information is needed if you expect decent assistance.

Comment: @Guy, an IP address does not uniquely identify a user.  Why not a session ID instead?  Or a random number plus microtime?

Comment: As I understand it, FontForge only defines one font as being 'open' at a time. Any command will only act on the 'open' font, so I'm not sure that using unique file names will solve the problem. It seems to me that I need FontForge to run in a unique instance for each user...

Comment: @Brad, yeah, sure. I would personally use `uniqid('[sanitized font name]', TRUE)`. Wasn't trying to give the final answer to @danielfaraday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not only have to worry about two users colliding but also one user colliding with himself via multiple requests.

To try and force one font action request per user, you could create pid-like files (but using user id instead of the process id) or you could create a queue of requests (e.g., in a database table) and have a daemon periodically check this queue (setting the `working` column to `1`) for requests by a particular user. Couple this with unique temp working directories per user and collisions will be unlikely.

Either approach has the potential for getting "stuck" (process ends before it can clear the mechanism). This can be combatted by having the daemon process clear the `working` flags upon its restart.

If you're not worried about simultaneous requests (via policy) and simply want to avoid collisions, you can forgo any daemons and **have your PHP script copy the font files into a newly created uniquely named folder for each request**, then copy the resulting font out of it upon completion.

Comment: Any one user will only be able to convert one font at a time (as a matter of policy), so I'm only worried about collisions between multiple users. Unfortunately, I think the queue is the only way to do this. As I mentioned above, FontForge only defines one font as being 'open' at a time. Any command will only act on the 'open' font, so unique file names alone doesn't solve the problem (I'm already creating unique file names using the uniqid() command in PHP).

Comment: Now that I think about it, is it even possible for two shell commands to run simultaneously? Won't one naturally wait for the other?

Comment: If their invoked by two different web requests they can absolutely run at the same time.

Comment: Thanks webbiedave - that makes sense.